# Edit text in frame android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, text

How to make it "Bold" and change color ? somebody can help me ? I try many times but still not working.

```js
Core.putText(mRgba, "Result : " +
             contours.size(), new org.opencv.core.Point(0, 300),
             Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.6f, new Scalar(255, 255, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.11/org/opencv/core/Core.html#putText(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.lang.String,%20org.opencv.core.Point,%20int,%20double,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar,%20int)): you have parameters for both of them.

```
public static void putText(Mat img,
    java.lang.String text,
    Point org,
    int fontFace,
    double fontScale,
    Scalar color,
    int thickness)
```

> #### Parameters:
>
> - img - Image.
> - text - Text string to be drawn.
> - org - Bottom-left corner of the text string in the image. fontFace - Font type. One of FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, or FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX, where each of the font ID's can be combined with FONT_ITALIC to get the slanted letters.
> - fontScale - Font scale factor that is multiplied by the font-specific base size.
> - **color** - Text color.
> - **thickness** - Thickness of the lines used to draw a text.

Then:

```
Core.putText(mRgba, 
    "Result : " + contours.size(),         
    new org.opencv.core.Point(0, 300),    
    Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,         
    2.6f,                             
    new Scalar(255, 255, 0), // color in BGR format, you should change this one
    2 // thickness (can be used to achieve bold)
)
```

Comment: When i try this  Core.putText(mRgba, "Count number : " +
             contours.size(), new org.opencv.core.Point(0, 300),
             Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.6f, new Scalar(255, 255, 0)2.0); shown "Syntax error"

Comment: @MTStuart Yes, because you are missing a comma after the color. This `[...] new Scalar(255, 255, 0)2.0)` should be `[...] new Scalar(255, 255, 0), 2)`

Comment: am i do wrong ? still cannot :  Core.putText(mRgba, "Result: " + contours.size(), new org.opencv.core.Point(0, 300), Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.6f, new Scalar(255, 255, 255)2);

Comment: @MTStuart you are still missing the comma before the `2` -> `,2`

Comment: oh yes, really sorry sir. Thanks for you kindness :)

Comment: @MTStuart no problem. Mark this as answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112959/discussion-between-mtstuart-and-berriel).