# OpenCV fonts in Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv

Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
Give me an error saying that such a symbol does not exist there, thus my question is how can i reference to provided fonts from OpenCv?

Comment: Please visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't given the whole code, it is hard to pin point your error.

I think it has to do how you are calling your font.

**Instead of:** Core.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

**Use:** Point FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

As explained already in this post: [Edit text in frame android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445202/edit-text-in-frame-android)

If it doesn't answer your question, please clarify more when asking. Have a nice day.